# Privilege Tracking Display Misformatted

Tags: bug

Yesterday, the privilege tracker looked like this:

[image]

Today, it looks like this:

[image]

Note how the privilege overlaps the "Next Privilege" and triggering rep level.

(Chrome 67, Windows 7, 64-bit)